# ImageIO.write only write certain images with format=jpeg

Tags: java, png, jpeg, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have the following code:

```
val resizedImage = Scalr.resize(inputImage, Scalr.Method.QUALITY, Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH, width)

val result = ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", outputStream)
```

The BufferedImage I provide always comes from a PNG file that I've read, and then processed to resize it using Scalr library. I don't think the Scalr part is really interesting but I included it in case...

This code works fine most of the time, but for some images (not random), it returns false constantly. Using format=png seems to always work, while jpeg/jpg seems to work in most cases.

Can someone explain me why some of my images might not be able to be written a jpg format? What can I do to be sure to write these images correctly?

I even tried to increase the JVM support for JPG by adding this lib. It worked to support TIFF but it didn't help to solve my JPG problem: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys

Here's a PNG for which the problem happen: https://files.stample.co/stample-1478606412313-imagemagick-pdfPreview1484802533410454080.png

Comment: Are your failing images 1-bpp?

Comment: did you put saclr on the tags??

Comment: Perhaps PNGs with palette (`IndexColorModel`) is the problem? JPEG (JFIF format) is suitable for storing 8 bit gray or 24 bit RGB, and not much else. It would help determine the cause if you can attach or link one of the PNGs that causes problems.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I've included in my question a PNG that always fails

Comment: @haraldK I must admit I'm not an image expert, just wondering what might be the problem and if there's a possible solution to increase my png to jpg conversion rate

Comment: The first thing I see about your sample PNG is that it uses 16 bits/sample RGB (or 48 bits/pixel). Converting it to a more common 8 bits/sample or 24 bits/pixel (like `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` or `TYPE_INT_RGB`) before writing as a JPEG will most likely solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that hint. I'm not really sure what this means yet nor how to do that conversion but will give it a try

Comment: I am seeing the same problem with this image which came from a WebP reader: BufferedImage@...: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 1366 height = 833 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0. Reconstructing the image from its pixels solves the problem.

Comment: Code that reconstructs the image when necessary: http://code.botcompany.de/1004891